# CodeIgniter get table count rows

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter, I want to count all rows from database table but i use limit in query and i want all count without use limit how can i do ?

my code is below :

```
  $sql = " SELECT intGlCode,fkCategoryGlCode,'C' as acctyp,varEmail,varContactNo as phone,CONCAT(varFirstName,' ',varLastName) as name,dtCreateDate,chrStatus,varMessage as message
  FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "Customer WHERE varEmail='$userEmail'
          UNION 
         SELECT intGlCode,'' as fkCategoryGlCode,'P' as acctyp,varEmail,varPhoneNo as phone,varName as name,dtCreateDate,chrStatus,txtDescription as message FROM  
      " . DB_PREFIX . "Power WHERE varEmail='$userEmail' ORDER BY intGlCode DESC 
     LIMIT $start, $per_page  ";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql)
```

i use limit for pagination but i want to get all record from table.

Comment: and this is proper query from union  in codeigntor?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new column in both above and below UNION queries. It will be like below.

```
select (select count(*) from your_query), your_columns from query_above_union 
UNION 
select (select count(*) from your_query), your_columns from query_below_union
```

your_query = your full actual query your are using currently.

Although I am not sure about Codeigniter. But sure about SQl.

Answer (score 0):

*** If you count all records with all data including limit, than you can use this code. please check it. I hope it will works for you.***

```
$countsql = " SELECT intGlCode,fkCategoryGlCode,'C' as acctyp,varEmail,varContactNo as phone,CONCAT(varFirstName,' ',varLastName) as name,dtCreateDate,chrStatus,varMessage as message
 FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "Customer WHERE varEmail='$userEmail'
      UNION 
     SELECT intGlCode,'' as fkCategoryGlCode,'P' as acctyp,varEmail,varPhoneNo as phone,varName as name,dtCreateDate,chrStatus,txtDescription as message FROM  
  " . DB_PREFIX . "Power WHERE varEmail='$userEmail' ORDER BY intGlCode DESC";
$sql = $countsql. " LIMIT $start, $per_page";  
$totalRecords   = $this->db->query($countsql);
$result["total_rows"] = $totalRecords->num_rows();
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result["list"] = $query->result_array();
```